# Why is a TextEditChange() in bUnit suddenly not working

Tags: blazor, devexpress, blazor-server-side, bunit

This was working and now does not. This is for a pretty simple page. I use DevExpress and `emailTextBox` is a `DxTextBox`.

This is successful

```
var emailTextBox = allTextBoxes.Single(x => x.Instance.InputId == "email");

emailTextBox.TextEditChange("");
button.Click();
var li = renderedComponent.Find("li.validation-message");
Assert.NotNull(li);
Assert.Equal("Your Email is required", li.InnerHtml);
Assert.Equal("", pageModel.Email);
```

Then this code immediately follows - and fails.

```
emailTextBox.TextEditChange("bogus");
button.Click();
li = renderedComponent.Find("li.validation-message");
Assert.NotNull(li);
Assert.Equal("The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.", li.InnerHtml);
Assert.Equal("bogus", pageModel.Email);
```

The problems are:

1. The error message it finds is the message for an empty field.
2. `pageModel.Email` is "".
3. In the debugger I look at `emailTextBox.Text` and it is "".

Is `TextEditChange()` not the right way to set the value in `DxTextBox`?

**Update:**

And sometimes randomly the above 2nd test passes, but then the next test, which is similar, fails. These tests assume that not only the `<input>` value is being set, but that the `<DataAnnotationsValidator/>` and `<ValidationSummary/>` have then run.

**Update 2:**

The following works:

```
emailTextBox.TextEditChange("bogus");
button.Click();
renderedComponent.Render();
li = renderedComponent.Find("li.validation-message");
Assert.NotNull(li);
Assert.Equal("The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.", li.InnerHtml);
Assert.Equal("bogus", pageModel.Email);
```

Is it required to call `renderedComponent.Render()` after the TextEditChange/Click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a lot of help from the bUnit team on this and the fundamental answer is twofold.

First, I need to make each `TextEditChange()` & `Click()` test a separate unit test. Doing several in a row is asking for trouble because the page elements all stay the same and it's just the text that changes.

Second, do a `WaitFor`, usually on the `renderedComponent.Find()` with a timeout. The unit test thereby tests for the expected change not by asserting the value, but by throwing an exception if the expected change does not get rendered before the timeout.

```
emailTextBox.TextEditChange("bogus");
button.Click();
var li = renderedComponent.WaitForElement("li.validation-message", Timeout);
Assert.NotNull(li);
```